# empty textarea puts string on database

Tags: html

I replaced some input texts to textarea.
Now when I save the content in database, the textarea is saving a string "  " in database. As it's a empty content, I want to save null on database, like it happens with the input text field.
Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: or the closing `</textarea>` is in a new line.

Comment: what database are you using? what language are you writing in? textarea inputs are never null, so you need to check the value's length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two spaces in my element. Take look at the code:

```
            <li class="comentarios">
            <label for="comentarios">Comentários:</label>
            <textarea type="text" rows="5" cols="50"> @comentarios </textarea>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
if(empty($_POST['textarea'])){
     $_POST['textarea']=NULL;
}
```

You would also need to make sure that the SQL column supports NULL values.

Comment: my bad I just assumed you were using PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something to sanitize user input before it's added to the database in the first place. If the string is empty, have your sanitizer change it to `null` before it is saved.

You might benefit from reading an article on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (I'm assuming you're working with PHP, but this topic is valid for any code that connects to a database).